# Search for text string, copy the found text and paste into a new cell

Tags: excel, vba, string, find

I currently have 1 column, whereby in 1 particular cell I have 3/4 text strings separated by line breaks.

ABC12345

DEF12345

XYZ12345

QWE12345

I basically just want to search that cell (A1) for the text starting ABC and copy paste into cell A2.

Then search for the DEF text and copy and paste into cell A3.

The text will change each time I run the VBA but the first 3 characters will always remain the same (ABC) which is why I want to use that as the search basis.

Comment: A potential route would be to `Split` your string by the line break (`Char(10)`). Then you could run a loop to check for values. Do you only want to search for "ABC" and "DEF"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Hi()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Target, Arr
Dim i As Long, x As Long

Target = Array("ABC", "DEF")
Arr = Split(ws.Range("A1"), Chr(10))

For i = LBound(Target) To UBound(Target)
    For x = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        If Left(Arr(x), 3) = Target(i) Then
            ws.Range("A" & i + 2) = Arr(x)
        End If
    Next x
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @Martin - we take our 'thanks' here in the form of accepting solutions that solved your problem. If this code works as you wanted, please accept (check mark to left of this solution)